# Wrong labeldate using biblatex authoryear style and shorthands

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, shorthands

I have a bibliography with multiple works by the same author, which were also published in the same year. I am using Biblatex's authoryear style, so, as expected, I get *Author (2020a)* and *Author (2020b)* in-text.

Some works, however, are referenced to via shorthand. I am thus printing a list of abbreviations. In that list, the years are mixed up: The work with the shorthand gets the wrong appendix for the year (see MWE and output below).

I think I have read most of Biblatex's manual by now. I also tried to print the shorthands myself using Bibliography Checks, and that worked, but the styling was aweful since the shorthand labels were not set apart from the rest of the entry. I would also prefer a non-hacky solution. The problem seems to be how `\printbiblist` differs from `\printbibliography`; but I really have come to a halt now and don't know how to proceed. Any help or even nudge in the right direction is appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mwe}

\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
  @book{Author_2020,
    title = {Some Title},
    author = {Some Author},
    year = {2020},
    location = {Someplace}
  }
  @book{Author_2020_2,
    title = {Some Other Title},
    shorthand = {MOT},
    author = {Some Author},
    year = {2020},
    location = {Someplace}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \section{Section}
    I am citing \cite{Author_2020} and \cite{Author_2020_2}.
    \printbiblist{shorthand}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Minimal Working Example Output]

Comment: I suggest you post your solution as a stand-alone answer (and remove it from the question). It may be useful for other people as well and it makes things slightly easier to follow.

Comment: I don't often post on SE; so I'm not that familiar with the etiquette. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky issue and might be classified as a bug (if my suspicions about how the issue arises are right, one might try to argue it is not a bug, but in any case it is very, very unexpected behaviour). I reported the issue at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1009.

---

In the meantime here is a workaround in case you are OK with not having the `extradate` letter for entries with `shorthand`s.

The command `\DeclareExtradate` regulates the scope of the `extradate` letter added to years to make citation labels unique. You can add `\field{shorthand}` to the current definition ([`biblatex.def`, ll. 1350-1355 in v3.14](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L1350-L1355))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}

\DeclareExtradate{%
  \scope{
    \field{shorthand}
    \field{labelyear}
    \field{year}
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Author_2020,
  title    = {Some Title},
  author   = {Some Author},
  year     = {2020},
  location = {Someplace}
}
@book{Author_2020_2,
  title     = {Some Other Title},
  shorthand = {MOT},
  author    = {Some Author},
  year      = {2020},
  location  = {Someplace}
}

@book{Buthor_2020_1,
  title    = {Some Title},
  author   = {Some Buthor},
  year     = {2020},
  location = {Someplace}
}
@book{Buthor_2020_2,
  title     = {Some Title},
  shorthand = {ZOT},
  author    = {Some Buthor},
  year      = {2020},
  location  = {Someplace}
}
@book{Buthor_2020_3,
  title    = {Some Title},
  author   = {Some Buthor},
  year     = {2020},
  location = {Someplace}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  I am citing \autocite{Author_2020} and \autocite{Author_2020_2}.

  I am citing \autocite{Buthor_2020_1,Buthor_2020_2,Buthor_2020_3}.

  \printbiblist{shorthand}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: I am citing (Author 2020) and (MOT).]

---

Here is a different solution that redefines `\printbiblist` so that the entries take their entry data from their default refcontext and not the refcontext of the biblist. In essence that means that all uniqueness info should still be as expected (the same as in citations and the bibliography), but the biblist will still be sorted correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@biblistitem#1{%
  \blx@getrefcontext{#1}%
  \blx@ifdata{#1}
    {\begingroup
     \blx@getdata{#1}%
     \blx@bibcheck
     \iftoggle{blx@skipentry}{}{%
       \blx@setdefaultrefcontext{#1}%
       \global\let\blx@noitem\@empty
       \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
       \blx@setoptions@entry
       \addtocounter{instcount}\@ne
       \iftoggle{blx@labelnumber}
         {\blx@bbl@locallabelnumberwidth}
         {}%
       \iftoggle{blx@labelalpha}
         {\blx@bbl@locallabelalphawidth}
         {}%
       \nottoggle{blx@skipbiblist}
         {\blx@bbl@locallabelfields}
         {}%
       \csuse{blx@item@\blx@theenv}\relax
       \csuse{blx@hook@biblistitem@\blx@thebiblist}%
       \blx@execute
       \blx@initunit
       \blx@beglangbib
       \bibsentence
       \blx@pagetracker
       \blx@driver{\blx@thebiblistdriver}%
       \blx@postpunct
       \blx@endlangbib}%
     \endgroup}
    {}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Author_2020,
  title    = {Some Title},
  author   = {Some Author},
  year     = {2020},
  location = {Someplace}
}
@book{Author_2020_2,
  title     = {Some Other Title},
  shorthand = {MOT},
  author    = {Some Author},
  year      = {2020},
  location  = {Someplace}
}

@book{Buthor_2020_1,
  title    = {Some Title},
  author   = {Some Buthor},
  year     = {2020},
  location = {Someplace}
}
@book{Buthor_2020_2,
  title     = {Some Title},
  shorthand = {ZOT},
  author    = {Some Buthor},
  year      = {2020},
  location  = {Someplace}
}
@book{Buthor_2020_3,
  title    = {Some Title},
  author   = {Some Buthor},
  year     = {2020},
  location = {Someplace}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  I am citing \autocite{Author_2020} and \autocite{Author_2020_2}.

  I am citing \autocite{Buthor_2020_1,Buthor_2020_2,Buthor_2020_3}.

  \printbiblist{shorthand}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was afraid of that! Because of style guidelines I can't do as you suggested. I will simply print my List of Shorthands using \printbibliography with a custom Bibliography Check (see my edited post) for the time being and monitor the bug report. Marking this as answered.

Comment: @Larissa Actually I just had an idea for a workaround. Check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to go deeper than expected, I suggest using the following workaround if you can't do as moewe suggested (not having `extradate` letters for entries with shorthands):

Define a new Bibliography Check:

```
\defbibcheck{isshorthand}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}{\skipentry}{}}
```

Define a new Sorting Template:

```
\DeclareSortingTemplate{snyt}{
  \sort{
    \field{shorthand}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}
```

Print your List of Shorthands:

```
\newrefcontext[sorting=snyt]
\printbibliography[check=shorthandset,env=shorthand,title=Abbreviations]
```

Reset the refcontext afterwards to the one you need, the default being `nyt`.

This will not look as pretty obviously, but in my case it gets the job done. MWE  and output below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Author_2020,
    title = {Some Title},
    author = {Some Author},
    year = {2020},
    location = {Someplace}
  }
  @book{Author_2020_2,
    title = {Some Other Title},
    shorthand = {MOT},
    author = {Some Author},
    year = {2020},
    location = {Someplace}
  }
  @book{Author_1900,
    title = {Some Other Title},
    shorthand = {LongShorthand},
    author = {Zop Zop},
    year = {1900},
    location = {Someplace}
  }
  @book{Author_1950,
    title = {Some Other Title},
    shorthand = {1950},
    author = {Zip Zap},
    year = {1950},
    location = {Someplace}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\defbibcheck{shorthandset}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}{\skipentry}{}}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{snyt}{
  \sort{
    \field{shorthand}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}


\begin{document}

\section{Section}

I am citing \cite{Author_2020} and \cite{Author_2020_2} and \cite{Author_1900} and \cite{Author_1950}.

\newrefcontext[sorting=snyt]
\printbibliography[check=shorthandset,env=shorthand,title=Abbreviations]
\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE 2]

Comment: Mhh, now that I read this again: Doesn't this also show the wrong year in the list of shorthands? The MOT entry `Author_2020_2` is 2020a in the bibliography and citations. (The underlying issue is that a new sorting scheme essentially means that you (can) get different `extradate`s from the ones in citations and the bibliography. As long as you change the sorting scheme, either implicitly as in `\printbiblist{shorthand}` or explicitly as done here, you run into the same issue.)

Comment: I definately need a day off. I honestly didn't see that; it totally makes sense. It worked without changing the sorting, but then it obviously is not sorted by `shorthand`.